# Efficiently load many views in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIScrollView that I am trying to use as an Image Viewer. For this I have paging enabled and I add "Slides" to the view for each Image, including a UIImageView and multiple labels and buttons. This works perfectly while I only have a few Slides to show, but I will need to have more than 100 of them, and I am running into really bad performance issues. 
When I present the ViewController, and therefore set up the ScrollView, I get a good 10-15s of delay. Apparently loading this many views is a little much.

So I was wondering if any of you had an idea how I could make this more efficient.

I have tried making the array of Slides in the previous VC, and passing it, instead of creating it on the spot, that helped a bit, but not enough to make it feel acceptable, especially since changing device orientation will require me to set the ScrollView up again (because the Slides height/width will be off).

Here are the functions to set up the Slides, and to present them on the ScrollView:

```
    func createSlides() -> [Slide] {
    print("creating Slides")

    let Essence = EssenceModel.Essence
    var ImageArray = [Slide]()

    var slide: Slide
    var count = 0


    for img in Essence{
        count += 1

        slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
        slide.imageView.image = UIImage(named: img.imageUrl)
        slide.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        slide.textLabel.text = img.description
        slide.likeButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        slide.hero.id = img.heroID

        slide.tag = count

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showOrHide))
        slide.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        let dismissGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissVC))

        slide.backButton.addGestureRecognizer(dismissGesture)
        slide.backButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipedUp))
        swipeUp.direction = .up
        slide.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipedDown))
        swipeDown.direction = .down
        slide.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

        let slideRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(startSlideshow))
        slide.slideButton.addGestureRecognizer(slideRecognizer)
        slide.likeButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        slide.setupZoom()

        ImageArray.append(slide)
    }
    count = 0
    print(ImageArray.count)
    return ImageArray
}


func setupSlideScrollView(slides : [Slide]) {
    scrollView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true

        for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
            slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

            scrollView.addSubview(slides[i])

        }
```

}

As I said, I am looking for ways of making this more efficient in any way so I can actually use it. Preferebly I would probably just load the Slide that I am on, the next and previous one, but I have no clue how I would go about doing that.

Here is also a Screenshot, so you can see what it looks like.

[image: w]
[image: w]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be better to do something like that:

1) Add UICollectionView

2) Add UITableViewCell with restorationID

3) Add relations to your controller/view

4) Set horizontal scroll direction: https://www.screencast.com/t/wmPiwVdY

5) And after that create logic something like that:

```
class ImageCollectionViewVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    private var images = [Slide]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let imageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageSlideCellRestorationID", for: indexPath) as? ImageSlideCell else {
            return ImageSlideCell()
        }
        imageCell.image.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row].imageUrl)
        return imageCell
    }
}


class ImageSlideCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the long answer! I ll try it as soon as i can, and sorry for the late response :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead using uiscroll and got a performance problems. You should using uicollectionview, scroll horizontal, custom cell with one image and buttons.